# fork() bomb explanation in terms of processes?

Tags: linux, operating-system, fork, system, virus

I am just wondering how a fork bomb works, I know that there are similar questions but the answers aren't quite what I am looking for (or maybe I just haven't been able to come across one)

**How does it work in terms of processes?**

Do children keep being produced and then replicating themselves? is the only way to get out of it is by rebooting the system?

Are there any long lasting consequences on the system because of a fork bomb?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a Google slave request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does it work in terms of processes?

It creates so many processes that the system is not able to create any more.

> Do children keep being produced and then replicating themselves?

Yes, [fork in the name means replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)).

> is the only way to get out of it is by rebooting the system?

No, it can be stopped by some automated security measures, eg. limiting the number of processes per user.

> Are there any long lasting consequences on the system because of a fork bomb?

A fork bomb itself does not change any data but can temporarily (while it runs) cause timeouts, unreachable services or OOM. A well-designed system should handle that but, well, reality may differ.